# Issue in installing Wamp server 64 bit on IIS7

Tags: php, .net, iis, iis-7, wampserver

I have IIS7 server to host my websites. Earlier I used .net technology but now i want to make a website in PHP and for back end I will use Mysql server. But I am facing a problem in installing Wamp server on my server because when I installed the Wamp server it show me orange color. And not trun in green color. And I cannot stop IIS7. So, I want to run both server. Please Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place for general computing help, or server-related help. Plus, your question is overly broad and hard for us to understand.

Comment: Dear Aaron it is simple have changed the 80 to 8080 still my wamp is in orange color ...It is my question that how can I change the color of wamp.

Answer (score 0):

Do not install apache if you have already an IIS server.
You can install for IIS the php "plugin", it is described on the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/install.windows.iis7.php) and then you can install a standalone MySQL server you can find a "guide" [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above)